# Flash cc + html 5: draw lines between moving objects

Tags: javascript, html, flash, flash-cc

I'm an animator trying to branch into coding and I'm a bit stuck with fundamentals.

This is a simple character walk cycle, and I'm trying to draw the legs with code [arcTo] between the body [ManBody] and the feet [foot01].

The lines draw on and the body moves - but the lines are redrawn on EVERY frame - How/Where do I stage.update(); so that it's just a single line that draws on to the stage, and then moves between the moving parts?

```
//mouse cursor
stage.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
this.ManBody.mouseEnabled = false;
this.addEventListener("tick", fl_CustomMouseCursor.bind(this));

function fl_CustomMouseCursor() {
    this.ManBody.x = (stage.mouseX+350) * 0.5 ;
    this.ManBody.y = (stage.mouseY+200) * 0.5;
}

//line
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",fl_DrawLineCont.bind(this));
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(10);

function fl_DrawLineCont(event) {

var stroke_color = "#ff0000";
var shape =  new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginStroke(stroke_color)
.moveTo(this.ManBody.x, this.ManBody.y)
.arcTo(this.foot01.x, this.foot01.y, this.ManBody.x, this.ManBody.y, 50).endStroke());
this.addChild(shape);
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creating shape every frame, you should create it outside of this and redraw it graphics like this:

```
var stroke_color = "#ff0000";
var graphics = new createjs.Graphics()
var shape = new createjs.Shape(graphics);
this.addChild(shape);
function fl_DrawLineCont(event)
{
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.beginStroke(stroke_color);
    graphics.moveTo(this.ManBody.x, this.ManBody.y).arcTo(this.foot01.x, this.foot01.y, this.ManBody.x, this.ManBody.y, 50).endStroke();
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the reply! @ices_2
it's working okay I just need to tweak the "ticker" as it's having some strange speed issues.